# Play-Framework 2.3.x: How to secure play-framework application URL

Tags: security, tomcat, authentication, playframework, netty

My basic requirement is that, i want to secure my play application URL. When user hit the url, there is a popup shown or basic authentication, for access application login page like in tomcat. In tomcat we can easily use basic authentication. But play uses `netty` server, how we do in `netty`?

Answer (score 0):

In play-framework, if we want to secure our URL with basic browser authentication, we need to handle this by programmatically as below:

```
object Application extends Controller {

private final val logger: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("Application")

val config: Configuration  = Play.application().configuration();

def index = Action { implicit request =>
 logger.info("Serving index page...")

 val authorization = request.headers.get("Authorization");
 if(!authorization.isEmpty) {
   val cridentials = new String(Base64.getDecoder.decode(request.headers.get("Authorization").get.substring(5).trim()));
   val arr = cridentials.split("\\:");
   if(!arr.isEmpty && arr.apply(0).equalsIgnoreCase(config.getString("username")) && arr.apply(1).equalsIgnoreCase(config.getString("password"))){
    Ok(views.html.index());
   }else {
     Unauthorized("Protected Security").withHeaders(
       "WWW-Authenticate" -> "Basic realm=Protected Security"
     )
   }
 }else{
   Unauthorized("Protected Security").withHeaders(
     "WWW-Authenticate" -> "Basic realm=Protected Security"
   )
 }}}
```